# mandrill break reset password instruction with devise 2.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise, mandrill

All my emails in local works fine with my gmail account. However in production env, I'm using [mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) to deliver the email.

My problem is when a user want reset the password. This is my email config in production:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com' }
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
 config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
 config.action_mailer.asset_host = "mydomain.com"

  ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'hyperrjas@mydomain.com'
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 25,
    :user_name => Settings.email.username,
    :password  => Settings.email.password
  }
```

This is my mailer controller:

```
require 'digest/sha2'
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
default "Message-ID"=>"#{Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(Time.now.to_i.to_s)}@mydomain.com"
  def confirmation_instructions(record, opts={})
    set_locale(record)
    headers["template_path"] = "user_mailer"
    headers["template_name"] = "confirmation_instructions"
    headers({'X-No-Spam' => 'True', 'In-Reply-To' => 'hyperrjas@mydomain.com'})
    super
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={})
    set_locale(record)
    headers["template_path"] = "user_mailer"
    headers["template_name"] = "reset_password_instructions"
    headers({'X-No-Spam' => 'True', 'In-Reply-To' => 'hyperrjas@mydomain.com'})
    super
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record, opts={})
    set_locale(record)
    headers["template_path"] = "user_mailer"
    headers["template_name"] = "unlock_instructions"
    headers({'X-No-Spam' => 'True', 'In-Reply-To' => 'hyperrjas@mydomain.com'})
    super
  end
  private
  def set_locale(user)
    I18n.locale = user.locale || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

This is the link with the problem in production:

```
<%= link_to "Change password", edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token) %>
```

Mandrill generate a link something like:

```
http://mandrillapp.com/track/click.php?u=30029014&id=890aac6b235b4802883f75b484d5ac8f&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fusers%2Fpassword%2Fedit&url_id=18754ce20fc88b338f0aa3993686e33be8ab84a1
```

However in development is working fine:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=yzYyyZuZArq7ksLZdgh3
```

When use click on link I can see the error:

```
You can't access this page without coming from a password reset email. If you do come from a password reset email, please make sure you used the full URL provided
```

How can I fix this error with mandrill?

Thanks!

Comment: What provider are you using to host the production app?

Comment: My provider is digitalocean. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the problem with the next code:

```
def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={})
  set_locale(record)
  headers["template_path"] = "user_mailer"
  headers["template_name"] = "reset_password_instructions"
  headers({'X-No-Spam' => 'True', 'In-Reply-To' => 'hyperrjas@mydomain.com'})
  headers['X-MC-Track'] = "False, False"
  super
end
```

You must add `headers['X-MC-Track'] = "False, False"` to your action `reset_password_instructions`

You can see the doc in the mandrill help from http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21688056-Using-SMTP-Headers-to-customize-your-messages#enable-open-and-click-tracking

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you turn of click tracking in Mandril, it shouldn't replace your URL with its own.  Then your links should work as expected.  Play around with it and see if you can disable it for only the confirmation emails:

When you do the API call to send, make sure to set `"track_clicks": false`
https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html

Alternatively, you could create a custom route, such as `http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit/token/yzYyyZuZArq7ksLZdgh3`, where the `password_token` is part of the path rather than part of the params (the part after the `?`).  Then you could handle that path and grab the `password_token` from it before passing along to Devise.

The first method is probably easier.  You don't really need click tracking on confirmation emails, since you'll know whether or not they clicked based on whether or not they visit your site and confirm!

Comment: Where can I turn off click tracking? In Mandrill panel controll or in my rails app? Can you paste a example? Thank you

Comment: The custom route does not seem to make a difference.  Still breaking in IE8 sometimes

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to turn it off globally, you can do it through the web UI.

You can get there through Mandrillapp or through Heroku.

For your app:

Click on Mandrill > Settings > Sending Defaults > Track Clicks (No click tracking)